# Issue with webgl coloring

Tags: webgl

I'll start off by saying that I'm new to webgl, only picked it up a few days ago for a computer graphics class and I'm having a problem with an application using dat.gui. What it's supposed to do is draw a rectangle with 2 clicks and color it with the color selected with the dat.gui controller, but the color that I get is a sort of a mix going from green, yellow, red and left bottom corner is black. If I comment the gl.enableVertexAttribArray(_color); line the rectangles are all black, so all I can think of is I'm not storing the color information correctly. I would very much appreciate it if someone could point me towards a solution or at least towards the problem. `

```html
<html>

<body>
  <canvas width="570" height="570" id="my_Canvas"></canvas>
  <script src="../lib/dat.gui.js"></script>
  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('my_Canvas');
    gl = canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
    var vertCode =
      'attribute vec3 coordinates;' +
      'varying vec3 vColor;' +
      'attribute vec3 color;' +
      'void main(void){' +
      ' gl_Position=vec4(coordinates, 1.0);' +
      'vColor=color;' +
      '}';

    var vertShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

    gl.shaderSource(vertShader, vertCode);
    gl.compileShader(vertShader);

    var fragCode =
      'precision highp float;' +
      'varying vec3 vColor;' +
      'void main(void){' +
      ' gl_FragColor=vec4(vColor, 1.0);' +
      '}';

    var fragShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(fragShader, fragCode);
    gl.compileShader(fragShader);

    var shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertShader);
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragShader);
    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

    console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertShader));
    console.log(gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));

    var gui = new dat.GUI();

    var colore = {
      colorv: [200, 200, 0]
    };

    gui.addColor(colore, 'colorv');

    gl.clearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    var g_indices = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3];
    var colors = [];
    var p_counter = 0; //this counter is used to detect if the point clicked is the 2nd point
    var g_counter = 0; //this is a global counter, used as a multiplier for g_points
    var quad_g_counter;
    var dodeca_g_counter;
    var g_points = []; // the array for mousepress
    var indices = [];
    var vertex_buffer = gl.createBuffer();
    var Index_Buffer = gl.createBuffer();
    var color_Buffer = gl.createBuffer();

    function click(ev, gl, canvas) {
      var x = ev.clientX;
      var y = ev.clientY;
      var rect = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect();
      x = ((x - rect.left) - canvas.height / 2) / (canvas.height / 2);
      y = (canvas.width / 2 - (y - rect.top)) / (canvas.width / 2);

      //store the coords in g_points array
      g_points.push(x);
      g_points.push(y);
      g_points.push(0);

      // clear <canvas>
      gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      p_counter += 1;
      if (p_counter == 2) {
        //g_points
        dodeca_g_counter = g_counter * 12;

        g_points.push(g_points[dodeca_g_counter + 3]);
        g_points.push(g_points[dodeca_g_counter + 1]);
        g_points.push(0);

        g_points.push(g_points[dodeca_g_counter]);
        g_points.push(g_points[dodeca_g_counter + 4]);
        g_points.push(0);

        //indices
        quad_g_counter = g_counter * 4;

        indices.push(g_indices[0] + quad_g_counter);
        indices.push(g_indices[1] + quad_g_counter);

        indices.push(g_indices[2] + quad_g_counter);
        indices.push(g_indices[3] + quad_g_counter);

        indices.push(g_indices[4] + quad_g_counter);
        indices.push(g_indices[5] + quad_g_counter);

        //colors
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) {

          colors.push(colore.colorv[0] / 255);
          colors.push(colore.colorv[1] / 255);

          colors.push(colore.colorv[2] / 255);

        }

        p_counter = 0;
        g_counter += 1;
      }

      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
      gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(g_points), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
      //gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

      //gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, Index_Buffer);
      gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

      //gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, color_Buffer);
      gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

      draw();
    }

    canvas.onmousedown = function(ev) {
      click(ev, gl, canvas);
    }

    function draw() {
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);

      var coord = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "coordinates");

      gl.vertexAttribPointer(coord, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
      gl.enableVertexAttribArray(coord);

      var _color = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");
      gl.vertexAttribPointer(_color, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
      gl.enableVertexAttribArray(_color);

      gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

      gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, Index_Buffer);

      gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You do not need to double-space your code. Use blank lines to separate logical pieces of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind the proper vertex buffer before you call `gl.vertexAttribPointer`:

```
var coord = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "coordinates");
var _color = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");

.....

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(coord, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(coord);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, color_Buffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(_color, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(_color);
```

Note, [`gl.vertexAttribPointer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/vertexAttribPointer) define an array of generic vertex attribute data refering to the currently bound `ARRAY_BUFFER`. See [`gl.bindBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/bindBuffer).

Before you specify the vertex attributes for `"coordinates"` you bind `vertex_buffer`. But you don't bind `color_Buffer` befor you specify the vertex attributes for `"color"`.
Because of that the vertex coordinate buffer is used for the color attributes too. his causes colorful lines and areas, because the colors are interpolated from point to point.

See the snippet:

```js
    var canvas = document.getElementById('my_Canvas');
     gl = canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
    
    var vertCode=
    'attribute vec3 coordinates;' +
    'varying vec3 vColor;' +
    'attribute vec3 color;' +
    'void main(void){' +
    '   gl_Position=vec4(coordinates, 1.0);' +
    'vColor=color;' +
    '}';
  
    var vertShader=gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(vertShader, vertCode);
    gl.compileShader(vertShader);
    
    var fragCode=
    'precision highp float;' +
    'varying vec3 vColor;' +
    'void main(void){' +
    '   gl_FragColor=vec4(vColor, 1.0);' +
    '}';
    
    var fragShader=gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(fragShader, fragCode);
    gl.compileShader(fragShader);
    
    var shaderProgram=gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertShader);
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragShader);
    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);
    console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertShader));
    console.log(gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
    
    //var gui = new dat.GUI();
    var colore={
        colorv: [200,200,0]
    };
    
    //gui.addColor(colore, 'colorv');
    gl.clearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    var g_indices=[0,1,2,0,1,3];
    var colors=[];
    var p_counter=0; //this counter is used to detect if the point clicked is the 2nd point
    var g_counter=0; //this is a global counter, used as a multiplier for g_points
    var quad_g_counter;
    var dodeca_g_counter;
    var g_points = []; // the array for mousepress
    var indices=[];
    var vertex_buffer=gl.createBuffer();
    var Index_Buffer=gl.createBuffer();
    var color_Buffer=gl.createBuffer();
    
    function click(ev,gl,canvas){
    
        var x = ev.clientX;
        var y = ev.clientY;   
        var rect = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    
        x = ((x - rect.left) - canvas.height/2)/(canvas.height/2);
        y = (canvas.width/2 - (y - rect.top))/(canvas.width/2);
    
        //store the coords in g_points array
    
        g_points.push(x);g_points.push(y); g_points.push(0);

        // clear <canvas>
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        p_counter+=1;
    
        if(p_counter==2){
    
            //g_points
            dodeca_g_counter=g_counter*12;
            g_points.push(g_points[dodeca_g_counter+3]);g_points.push(g_points[dodeca_g_counter+1]);g_points.push(0);
            g_points.push(g_points[dodeca_g_counter]);g_points.push(g_points[dodeca_g_counter+4]);g_points.push(0);
    
            //indices
            quad_g_counter=g_counter*4;
            indices.push(g_indices[0]+quad_g_counter);indices.push(g_indices[1]+quad_g_counter);
            indices.push(g_indices[2]+quad_g_counter);indices.push(g_indices[3]+quad_g_counter);
            indices.push(g_indices[4]+quad_g_counter);indices.push(g_indices[5]+quad_g_counter);
    
            //colors
    
            for(var i=0; i<4; i+=1){
                colors.push(colore.colorv[0]/255);colors.push(colore.colorv[1]/255);
                colors.push(colore.colorv[2]/255);
            } 
            p_counter=0;
            g_counter+=1;
        }
    
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(g_points), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    
            //gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);    
            //gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
  
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, Index_Buffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  
            //gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, color_Buffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            draw();
    }
    
    canvas.onmousedown = function(ev) {click(ev,gl,canvas);}
    
    function draw(){
    
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
        var coord=gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "coordinates");
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(coord, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(coord);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, color_Buffer);
        var _color=gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(_color, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0,0);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(_color);
        gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);
    
        gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, Index_Buffer);
        gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    }
```

```html
<canvas width="570" height="570" id="my_Canvas"></canvas>
```